# NextJS <Link> Takes me to 404

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, next.js

I've seen this question asked around online Im trying to implement suggested solution but still not working for me. So my apologies for the duplicate.

Anyway I have a simple link tag which is throwing a 404

```
<Link className={classes.navbarDesktopMenuButton} href="/profile/[id]" as={`/profile/${username}`}>
  <Button>
    <strong className={classes.navbarDesktopMenuButton}>My Profile</strong>
  </Button>
</Link>
```

I am quite certain im navigating to the right route so not sure why i am still getting the 404.

[image]

Note if i navigate on the first time it will 404 for like a second then the page will popup. But if i navigate out of the page then navigate back then its just stuck on the 404 the 2nd 3rd 4th time etc.

I know its some nextjs thing that I'm just misunderstanding since the route works fine if I were to use < a > tags instead of < Link > tags

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
<Link
    className={classes.navbarDesktopMenuButton}
    href={{
        pathname: "/profile/[id]",
        query: { id: username },
    }}
    as={`/profile/${username}`}
>
    <Button>
        <strong className={classes.navbarDesktopMenuButton}>My Profile</strong>
    </Button>
</Link>
```

Comment: still hit the 404 when i do this

Comment: @benjamin852 it works for me i tested this do you have profile folder in pages directory? please check this,may it will help.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response again, turns out my code was correct as was yours there was an issue on my component i still have to investigate further but dont think my Link was the problem thanks again for the answer and will mark yours as correct.

Answer (score 0):

use 'a' tag, inside the Link tag.

https://nextjs.org/docs/tag/v9.5.2/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes

for lastest versions of nextjs:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

Comment: tried to take out the button and replace with an < a > tag but still hits the 404

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use an anchor tag instead of the button component, but the rest of this code should make it work!

```
<Link className={classes.navbarDesktopMenuButton} href={`/profile/${username}/`}>
    <Button>
        <strong className={classes.navbarDesktopMenuButton}>My Profile</strong>
    </Button>
</Link>
```

Comment: switched it to the <a> tag in the <link> still hitting the 404 though